# saving scraped items to json/csv/xml file using scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I am learning [Scrapy](http://scrapy.org/)(A web crawling framework) from their [official doc](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/).
By following examples and documentation I created my spider to scrape data using sitemap

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import SitemapSpider
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from MyProject1.items import MyProject1Item

class MySpider(SitemapSpider):
    name="myspider"
    sitemap_urls = ['http://www.somesite.com/sitemap.xml']
    sitemap_follow = ['/sitemapbrowsesection\d+']
    count=0
    def parse(self, response):
        self.count=self.count+1
        item=MyProject1Item()
        sel=Selector(response)
        item["exp"]=sel.xpath('/html/head/title/text()').extract()
        print str(self.count)+":\t"+response.url
        print sel.xpath('/html/head/title/text()').extract()
        print "\n\n"
```

I can see the scraped results on screen with log by running command
`scrapy crawl myspider`
I can save scraped results to json/csv/xml file by adding option in command
`scrapy crawl myspider -o item.json -t json` for getting results in [json](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) file.

My problem is that scrapy dumps scraped results to item.json only when scrapy is done with crawling. means  have to wait till crawling get over. so for big project I will have to wait for very very long time as I guess scrapy will write scraped results to json file after all the crawling to be done.

I want scrapy to write to json file promptly or almost promptly or in the mid of crawling so I can see the results of sites which have crawled while scrapy is running.

I know there must be something inbuilt in scrapy that I am not able to catch. I tried to get help from http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/feed-exports.html
and
http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/exporters.html
but not able to solve my problem. so I am looking for some help or example code otherwise I have to add few lines to `parse(self, response)` function to create json/csv file and write scrapped result into it.

Answer (score 1):

That's the way writing to a file works. There is a buffer that gets written to the disk only when it's full.

For example, in one shell open a file with python:

```
$ ipython

In [1]: fp = open('myfile', 'w')
```

In another shell monitor the file content:

```
$ tail -f myfile
```

Go back to the python shell and write some content:

```
In [2]: _ = [fp.write("This is my file content\n") for i in range(100)]
```

In my case, I don't see any content in the `tail` output. Write more content:

```
In [3]: _ = [fp.write("This is my file content\n") for i in range(100)]
```

Now I see the lines in the `tail` output.

In fact, you can change the file buffering (see [1]). Open again a file:

```
$ ipython

In [1]: fp = open('myfile', 'w', buffering=0)
```

Monitor the file content in another shell:

```
$ tail -f myfile
```

Write something and see the `tail` output:

```
In [2]: fp.write("Hello there\n")
```

It is good to have the buffering enabled (reduces the disk I/O). You items file will get the output eventually, but you might want to change the format to the default `jsonlines` (no `-t` argument needed), with that you get a json object per line. It's a highly used format for streaming.

You can read a `jsonlines` (`.jl` extension) easily:

```
import json

for line in open('items.jl'):
    data = json.loads(line)
    # do stuff with data
```

And even other tools like `head` + `json.tool` or `jq` (see [2]):

```
$ head -1 items.jl | python -m json.tool
$ jq -I . items.jl
```

I haven't seen any problem so far having a large job writing the items to a `.jl` file (or any other format). Nevertheless, if your job gets killed you will lost the last items in the buffer. This can be solved by storing the items in a db or something similar.

[1] http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open

[2] http://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/

Comment: I would simplify the answer and stick to recommending JSON Lines for the OP use case.

Answer (score 0):

`scrapy crawl myspider -o item.json -t json` saves fetched results while crawling only. I wont have to wait for crawling to get finished. I can see content of file item.json while crawler is running

so no need to include code for writing fetched data to file in spider.